# comment extraire le graphe dans une map android?

Tags: android

actually i m working in a android application to get the shorest way between two point in a map,
but I must use a database where the locations will be stored my problem is how to store them? if for example there is a way between point 0 and 1 we shouldn't show the way 1 to 0 ..! at end i must extract a graph from this map  based on locations who are in database...i just started if u have anything to help me i will ve thankfull
ps: sorry for my english !

Comment: Sorry, but this site is for questions written in English. (Google Translate: Désolé, mais ce site est destiné aux questions écrites en anglais.)

Comment: i translate it :D